# Java/Android Add List items to other list

Tags: java, android, list

I got a list from `responseObject` and a `rootObject` List. The `responseObject` list is filled with new items(objects with title,id,summary etc) and i want to add them to my `rootObject` List but i get the error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.List.add(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
```

Both lists are named results. Does anyone know how to add the items to my `rootObject` 
This is the code:

```
        public void success(RootObject responseObject, Response response) {
            rootObject.nextId = responseObject.nextId;
            rootObject.results.add(responseObject.results.get(0));
        }
```

I checked the response and there are items in the `responseObject` results

whole code:

```
public class NewsController {
        private RestAdapter restAdapter;
        public RootObject rootObject = new RootObject();
        public MainActivity ma;
        static final String API_URL = "http://SECRETAPILINK.SECRET/api";
        public void getNews(){
            OkHttpClient mOkHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
            mOkHttpClient.setConnectTimeout(15000,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            mOkHttpClient.setReadTimeout(15000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
            restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(API_URL).setClient(new OkClient(mOkHttpClient)).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL) .build();
            GetNewsService service = restAdapter.create(GetNewsService.class);

            Callback<RootObject> cb = new Callback<RootObject>() {
                @Override
                public void success(RootObject responseObject, Response response) {
                    Log.v("AASSAASS", responseObject.results.get(0).Title);
                    rootObject.nextId = responseObject.nextId;
                    rootObject.results.addAll(responseObject.results);
                    Log.v("AASSAASS", responseObject.results.get(0).Title);

                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    Log.v("AASSAA", error.toString());
                }
            };
            service.GetNewsItems(cb);
        }
    }
```

Comment: rootObject.results is null

Comment: Have you initialized the list returned by rootObjects.results?

Comment: Show initialization of `rootObject.results`. If you want to add all items in responseObject to rootObject, use [`addAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll(java.util.Collection)).

Comment: I added the complete code to the question. addAll gives the same null error

Comment: `addAll` wasn't supposed to solve the error. I was giving a suggestion that if you want to add all items from list A to list B, addAll is convenient. From the code, you have posted, you are not initializing `rootObject.results = new ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialized `rootObject.results` arrayList which is why it is throwing NPE.

To explain, lets look at a small example

```
class Ideone
{
    List<Integer> list;

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        try {
            Ideone id = new Ideone();
            id.list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            id.list.add(1);
            id.list.add(2);

            Ideone copyId = new Ideone();
            copyId.list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            copyId.list.addAll(id.list);

            Ideone npeId = new Ideone();
            npeId.list.add(id.list);      //->nullpointerexception

        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

In the above example, if you don't initialize `npeId`, it will throw a NPE.

In your code, you will need something like

```
rootObject.results = new ArrayList<...>();
```